# Firing a particle effect toward the tapped target

Tags: unity, c#

I am editing this game, where i have to destroy this pyramid when user will tap, i want to  show particle effect moving towards Pyramid Like this:

[image]

but sometime it is not moving towards pyramid like this but moving straight Like this:

[image]

Script for RayCast and Particle Effect Instantiation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class General : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject currentPyramid;
    RaycastHit Hit;
    public GameObject LineStart;
    public GameObject ParticleEffect;

    void Awake(){
    }
    void Start(){
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        Debug.Log (currentPyramid);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit ();
            bool Hit = Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),
                                       out hitInfo);
            if (Hit) {
                currentPyramid = hitInfo.transform.gameObject;
                if (currentPyramid != null) {
                    Instantiate (ParticleEffect,
                                 LineStart.transform.position,
                                 LineStart.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code for Pyramids

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PyramidScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Pyramid") == gameObject.name) {
            General.currentPyramid = this.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Physics.Raycast` generally stops for anything which has a collider, unless you use the layerMask parameter to limit it to objects with specific layers. You are not checking if the raycast hit is a pyramid. Could there be some other collider in the scene which you are hitting instead?

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate the effect at the collision point

```
Instantiate (ParticleEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.identity);
```